# How to write custom ContentHandler using Apache Tika?

Tags: java, html-parsing, apache-tika

I want to extract text which is inside some tags like `<dt>`, `<dd>`, etc. from HTML files using Apache Tika.

So I am writing  custom `ContentHandler` which is supposed to extract information from these tags.

My custom `ContentHandler` code looks like below. It is not yet complete but its already not working as expected :

```
public class TableContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

    // key = abbreviation
    // value = information / description for abbreviation
    private Map<String, String> abbreviations = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // current abbreviation
    private String abbreviation = null;

    // <dd> element contains abbreviation. So this boolean variable will be set when
    // <dd> element is found
    private boolean ddElementStarted = false;

    // this method is not giving contents within <dd> and </dd> tags
    public void characters(char[] chars, int arg1, int arg2) throws SAXException {
            if(ddElementStarted) {
                    System.out.println("chars found...");
            }
    }

    // set boolean ddElementStarted to true to indicate that content handler found 
    // <dd> element
    public void startElement(String arg0, String element, String arg2, Attributes arg3) throws SAXException {
            if(element.equalsIgnoreCase("dd")) {
                    ddElementStarted = true;
            }
    }
}
```

Here my assumption is that as soon as content handler goes inside `startElement()` method and element name is `dd` then I will set `ddElementStarted = true` and then to get contents inside `<dd>` and `</dd>` element, I will check in `characters()` method.

In `characters()` method I am checking if `ddElementStarted = true` and `chars` array will contents within `<dd>` and `</dd>` element, but it is not working :(

I would like to know if

1. Am I going in correct direction?
2. Is this the proper way to parse HTML using Tika? Or is there any other way?
3. Should I choose another HTML parsing API like JSoup? I just need information from couple of tags like, I am not interested in rest of the HTML page.
4. Is there any way to specify `XPath` expressions in Apache Tika? I am not able to find this information in `Tika in Action` book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). Easily we can get the values inside any tag. So instead of writing new ContentHandler just use JSoup to parse.